# Dojo Scrollable View - Scroll to Top

Tags: dojo

I have a dojo scrollable view which has a list of items (Say 100).
The user is provided with a button "Scroll to top".

When the user clicks it, I need to take him to the top of the scrollable view and the other contents on page must not get disturbed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using the below code.

```
Scrollable_View_Widget_Id.scrollTo({x:0 ,y: 0});
```

EDIT1:

Assume that you have the following declarative syntax for creating ScrollableView widget.

```
<div id="scrollView" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView" data-dojo-props="columns:'single'">
</div>
```

Then in you javascript code you need to use the widget id as defined above to scroll to the top.

```
scrollView.scrollTo({x:0 ,y: 0});
```